# Acces denied in windows git server

Tags: git, ssh

I created a repository **--bare** in one machine (server), in the others I'm trying to do the push , but I have that errors
if I create a repository in the client just with **git init** (client) and add the remote, when I do the push, i get this

> error does not appear to be a git repository could not read from
>   remote repository please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exist

If I try to clone the repository I get this.

> permission denied keyboard-interactive fatal could not read from remote

Im using  autentication with ssh password and using putty the ssh configuration is working good;

For the ssh   I´m using copSSH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem I miss to set .git in the end of my  --bare folder name , I changed from "myrepo" to "myrepo.git" and all works perfect.